# Google oAuth from express throws a Cross-Origin-Request error despite the express-cors headers

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, cors, google-oauth

In my React code this button will hit my express endpoint which responds with the following redirection url
`<GoogleButton onClick={this.googleLogin}/>`

**Response from express server:**

```
let url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=${clientID}&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:8084/api/v1/auth/login")}

res.render(url); //this is the response from my server
```

**My express cors header:**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {//In case I needed POST
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code might work

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

You can look at the cors npm package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors for additional options